# Kill screen session using java

Tags: java, shell, gnu-screen

I'm trying to kill a detatched screen session. Recently I have started a screen session with the following java code:

1. Just created a new ProcessBuilder:

   ```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "screen -mdS " + 
   servername + " java " + "-Xms256M -Xmx" + max_ram + "M -jar server.jar 
   ").directory(tempDirectory);
   ```
2. Started a new process

   ```
   try {

     Process p = pb.start(); // start a process
     subserver.setProcess(p); // save the process if we need it later again
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 

     InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     String line;
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
     }

   } catch (Exception e) {         
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

But the question is: How to kill this new process ?

Comment: Go through javadoc of Process Class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

It has destroy() method which can be used to kill the process.

Comment: The destroy() method doesnt work for me. Furthermore the isAlive() method of the process always return false. But the screen is still running. Is there any other way?

Comment: No need for `sh -c`.  Just execute screen directly:  `new ProcessBuilder("screen", "-mdS", servername, "java", "-Xms256M", "-Xmx" + max_ram + "M", "-jar", "server.jar")`.  Also, you can do away with your BufferedReader completely and instead call `pb.inheritIO();`, which will cause the process’s standard output to appear in your calling program’s standard output.